# How to combine lists between sql queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of users have watched a video (1017) that are returned from the query:

```
select distinct user_id from video_views 
where video_viewable_id = 1017;
```

I also have a different set of users (that pay) from the following query:

```
select id, is_paying_customer from users
where is_paying_customer = '1';
```

The user_id in video_views table is the same as id in the users table.  How do I write one query to display the list of users that both watched the video and are paying customers?

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct user_id from video_views 
where video_viewable_id = 1017 and user_id in (select id from users
where is_paying_customer = '1')
```

or you can use join syntax

```
select distinct user_id from video_views 
inner join users as t on (video_views.user_id=t.id and t.is_paying_customer = '1')
where video_viewable_id = 1017
```

also, as users is the main table, I would do it like:

```
select id from users where is_paying_customer = '1' and
`id` in (select user_id from from video_views where video_viewable_id = 1017)
```

in this case you do not need distinct and mysql will efficiently use indexes

Comment: What does the ### represent?

Comment: you forgot to put table name in second query, I've replaced it with ###

Comment: ### is the name of the second table. I would use the join method

Comment: @RaymondNijland need to benchmark both, as join will need distinct operation

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, the following should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT U.id
FROM users U
INNER JOIN video_views V
ON U.id = V.user_id 
WHERE V.video_viewable_id = 1017
AND U.is_paying_customer = '1'
```

The result will be a list of all users that are paying customers and that have watched a particular video.